# Why the total momentum and kinetic energy of a subatomic particle in a head-on collision is transferred to another particle?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, classical-mechanics, momentum, conservation-laws, collision

*"When two atomic particles collide (eg- 2 protons) on a single line:
At first, one proton is stationary and the other moving. When they collide, the total momentum and kinetic energy of the proton that was originally moving is transferred to the other proton, so that the one that was originally moving is now stationary and vice versa"*

Why does this happen specifically in atomic particles? 
Wouldn't there be electrostatic repulsion before the collision?
What determines whether two particles move together or not after a collision?

Comment: It's not only atomic particles, it's general.  Newton's cradle is an example.

Comment: Electrostatic repulsion **is** the collision.

Comment: this is an odd statement. What is the source? Classically, the kinematics isn't that special, and quantum mechanically, the protons are indistinguishable, so that what you have described in the t-channel is non-scattering in the u-channel.

Comment: @RogerJBarlow so why would the explanation note atomic particles directly? Because of negligible air resistnace?

Comment: You don't give the context - I'd assumed it was from a discussion about atomic particles

Comment: @RogerJBarlow No, it was just a general discussion about momentum and then the specific example of atomic particles was given, that's where my confusion comes from, because unless this is something specific to atomic particles, there is no need to mention them there

Comment: Then I guess it's because there is explicitly no loss of energy to sound, heat, or internal excitations of any sort. It's also true for perfectly elastic collisions between macroscopic balls etc and in the real world such collisions are not perfectly elastic - though they can get very close.

Answer (score 2):

This is an example of an elastic collision. Elastic means kinetic energy is conserved. Inelastic means some or all of the kinetic energy is transformed to another form such as heat.

Another very similar elastic example is two balls of equal mass colliding with a spring between them. When they collide, the spring compresses. This slows the incoming ball, converting kinetic energy to potential energy. Then the spring expands to its original size, pushing the outgoing ball away. The final state is the incoming ball is stopped, and the outgoing ball has the same velocity that the incoming ball had.

The hard way to figure out the final velocities is to carefully watch the balls, and calculate the forces at each instant. You would find that the total acceleration is just enough to bring the incoming ball to a stop. The total acceleration is just enough to give the outgoing ball the same velocity as the incoming ball had.

The easy way is to use the laws of conservation of energy and conservation of momentum. Momentum and energy are always conserved. In an elastic collision, kinetic energy is conserved, because none of it was converted to another form.

$$\frac{1}{2}mv_{1i}^2 = \frac{1}{2}mv_{1f}^2 + \frac{1}{2}mv_{2f}^2$$
$$mv_{1i} = mv_{1f} + mv_{2f}$$

For a straight-line collision, you can show there are two possible values for $v_{1f}$ and $v_{2f}$ that make both equations true.

$v_{1f} = v_{1i}$ and $v_{2f} = 0$. The balls do not collide. The incoming ball keeps on going. This is a valid solution, but does not describe this situation.

$v_{1f} = 0$ and $v_{2f} = v_{1i}$. The incoming ball stops. The outgoing ball gets the same speed as the incoming ball. It therefore gets the same momentum and kinetic energy as the incoming ball.